# Why put 158K resistor between the input signals and negative input signal and ground?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

In the istrumentation amplifier circuit below, why would someone put a 158K resistor between the input signals? Also, how about the 165K signal between the negtive input and ground?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The designer was thinking about the potential problems that might occur if the sensor was disconnected.  The Instrumentation Amplifier would have floating inputs - this can lead to all kinds of issues.

Remember that Hall Effect sensor (or bridge) is relatively-low impedance.  The designer chose resistor values that are high relative to the output impedance of the sensor.

Also note that there are two ways to connect those added resistors: as shown in the diagram **or** from each input to Ground.  The designer chose to do it the way (s)he did, as a guess, to reduce possible error caused by the resistors being in the circuit.  Again: look at the offset that is introduced by the ratio of the added resistors compared to the output impedance of the sensor.

In my opinion, these added resistors are a sign of good engineering practices.

Comment: Although I tend to agree with you.. I can't see why those particular/specific 1% values were chosen.

Comment: The resistor across the Instrumentation Amp inputs is easy - the designer used whatever was handy.  The resistor from the (-) input to ground may have been chosen to introduce a specific amount of offset.  Pretty hard to tell exactly why THOSE specific values were chosen.